# css code issue using style and div no answer online

Tags: jquery, css

would anyone know how I could increase the height of the menu when it scrolls up on this demo? The part that loads up with the links?

Demo:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CollapsingSiteNavigation I know it is something to do with the style CSS under submenu, but I would like to make it rise higher if that's possible? can anyone help? much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/09/06/collapsing-site-navigation/?

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Comment: I got it, in the main code on the m_enter section, the height is displayed on there, thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top of the ul that slides in from the bottom is being determined by the height that is given to it.  Being that it uses jQuery, the hover effect and height change, is most likely not being done with CSS.  When I browse to the CSS files that they are using, I see no indication of any :hover or css transitions.  I could be wrong, but this is my best answer